# Symmetric difference of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $ E \subset A$. Is it true that their symmetric difference is just $A \setminus E$? In other words, does it follow that

$$A \triangle E = A \setminus E$$ ?

thanks

Comment: In even simpler terms suppose you have sets $A$ and $B$ then the symmetric difference are all the elements in set $A$ and $B$ but $x\not\in A\cap B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. By definition of the symmetric difference we have:
$$
A\triangle E=(A\setminus E)\cup(E\setminus A)=A\setminus E
$$
as $E\setminus A=E\cap A^c=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Just for fun, here is another way to check this, by using the definition
$$
\tag{0} x \in X \triangle Y \;\equiv\; x \in X \not\equiv x \in Y
$$
We can now try and see what the elements $\;x\;$ of $\;A \triangle E\;$ are:

$$\calc
x \in A \triangle E
\calcop{\equiv}{definition (0) of $\;\triangle\;$, above}
x \in A \;\not\equiv\; x \in E
\calcop{\equiv}{separate out $\;\lnot\;$; split $\;\equiv\;$ into $\;\Rightarrow\;$ -- to allow us to use $\;E \subseteq A\;$}
\lnot ((x \in A \Rightarrow x \in E) \;\land\; (x \in E \Rightarrow x \in A))
\calcop{\equiv}{right hand side of $\;\land\;$ is true by $\;E \subseteq A\;$}
\lnot (x \in A \Rightarrow x \in E)
\calcop{\equiv}{expand $\;P \Rightarrow Q\;$ to $\;\lnot P \lor Q\;$; DeMorgan}
x \in A \;\land\; x \not\in E
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\setminus\;$}
x \in A \setminus E
\endcalc$$

By set extensionality, this indeed proves that $\;A \triangle E \;=\; A \setminus E\;$.